# Unix storing to variables

Tags: xcode, unix

I write the following line in a file which i run through cygwin:

```
idvisitor=cat visitor_for_room $1 $2 | cut -d " " -f 2 | sort
```

visitor_for_room is a script and $1 $2 r inputs in my script.
why do i get a print on the screen of the output? i tried to store it in the varibale idvisitor. it doesn't store it there but only prints it to the screen.
I tried spaces in different places an tried this symbol "`" at the begining and end of file - doesn't seem to work.
thanks.

Comment: I think `cat` in script execution is a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try your script like this -

```
dvisitor=$(visitor_for_room $1 $2 | cut -d " " -f 2 | sort)
```

Comment: thanks it works, if i want to make the variable idvisitor and array how do i do it?

Comment: You want to store the variable value in an array?

Comment: Welcome! and I got advise from expert to avoid the use of  back tick `"\`"` in script.